# Spring Webservice Client: Cannot handle SOAP faults

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

In my project I created a webservice client with Spring Web Services (2.0.4.RELEASE).

The webServiceTemplate is defined in my spring config:

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
<bean id="wsClient" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
</bean>
```

When I call the service (`wsClient.marshalSendAndReceive(...)`) and it returns a SOAP fault the webservice client doesn't recognize it.
It tries to marshall it and a ValidationException is thrown.

I looked at the Spring Web Service source code. In the WebServiceTemplate class exists a method `protected boolean hasFault(WebServiceConnection connection, WebServiceMessage response)`. But this method always returns false.

I already checked this question: [Java Spring Web Service Client Fault Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541836/java-spring-web-service-client-fault-handling)

The service sends the response with HTTP status code 500. So that is not the problem.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

EDIT: The application runs on a Weblogic 10.3.5

Comment: It is weird. I would debug hasFault method and see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not Spring Web Services. It was our webservice returning an invalid response. :-/

What I learned from this problem:

- soapUI has a great HTTP Monitor for recording SOAP traffic: http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-Recording/recording-soap-trafic.html
- Always check first if your requests and responses are valid according to your schema. (This can be done with one click in the soapUI HTTP Monitor)